# How to select variables inside the function?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following code and it is working perfectly. However I want to create a function that will help to change `df`,`X`,`Y1`,`Y2`.

```
ylim.prim <- c(0, max(df$Y1))  #line 
ylim.sec <- c(0,max(df$Y2))   # bar
b <- diff(ylim.prim)/diff(ylim.sec)
a <- b*(ylim.prim[1] - ylim.sec[1])

ggplot(data = df) + 
  geom_line(aes(x=X, y=Y1, color=kind), lwd=1.5)+
  geom_col(aes(x=X, y=a+Y2*b, fill=price_direction), position = position_dodge(), alpha=0.05)+ # color=price_direction
  scale_y_continuous( sec.axis = sec_axis(~ (. - a)/b, name = "Change"))+ 
  scale_fill_manual(values = alpha(c("red", "limegreen"), .3))
```

I want something like:

```
graph_history<-function(data,x,y,y2){
ylim.prim <- c(0, max(data$y))  #line 
ylim.sec <- c(0,max(data$y2))   # bar
b <- diff(ylim.prim)/diff(ylim.sec)
a <- b*(ylim.prim[1] - ylim.sec[1])

ggplot(data = data) + 
  geom_line(aes(x= {{ x}}, y= {{ y}}, color=kind), lwd=1.5)+
  geom_col(aes(x={{ x}}, y=a+{{y2}}*b, fill=price_direction), position = position_dodge(), alpha=0.05)+ # color=price_direction
  scale_y_continuous( sec.axis = sec_axis(~ (. - a)/b, name = "Change"))+ 
  scale_fill_manual(values = alpha(c("red", "limegreen"), .3))

}
```

I know that variables inside ggplot can be written inside  `{{ }}` , but what to do with the upper part when I use  `$`  notation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select columns based on variables, use `[[…]]` instead of `$…`:

```
ylim.prim <- c(0, max(data[[y]]))  # line 
ylim.sec <- c(0, max(data[[y2]]))  # bar
```

This works if you’re passing *values* to your function. However, if you’re using non-standard evaluation to pass unevaluated *names* to the function, you need to jump through a few more hoops:

```
yval <- as.character(substitute(y))
y2val <- as.character(substitute(y2))
ylim.prim <- c(0, max(data[[yval]]))  # line 
ylim.sec <- c(0, max(data[[y2val]]))  # bar
```

… or you can use a ‘dplyr’ function (`pull`), which support the same curly-curly syntax as `aes` from ‘ggplot2’:

```
ylim.prim <- c(0, max(pull(data, {{y}})))  # line 
ylim.sec <- c(0, max(pull(data, {{y2}})))  # bar
```

Comment: I tried it, but id did not work. I.e. `mydf<- data.frame(x1=c(1,2,3,4,5),x2=c(2,2,4,4,9))
test<-function(data,col){
  return(max(data[[col]], na.rm = TRUE))
}
test(mydf, x1)`